# Making Activity/Application completely Transparent

Tags: android, android-activity, transparent

I'm trying to make my application see-through to the previous application. I'm not using a floating service for this as it's supposed to be the home screen.

Setting the below on both the activity and application in the manifest

```
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
```

Only makes it so that it's a black screen. Is there a way to go fully transparent?

Answer (score 1):

It is fully transparent. What is behind it is black. Your activity is not in front of another activity on a task's back stack.

Comment: Understood. So in order to make it so, either the framework would need to be overridden, or the app needs to not be an app, or a fake screen shot needs to be taken of the screen and displayed before this happens?

Comment: @lawonga: You have limited abilities to take screenshots in Android, and I don't know exactly when you would take the screenshot. I do not know what "the app needs to not be an app" means. In terms of modifying Android (my interpretation of "the framework would need to be overridden"), presumably that could be done, though multi-window support may add to the complexity. And, of course, only people running your custom ROM would get the effect.